# Rails datepicker ActiveRecord Lookup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datepicker

I am using the `bootstrap-datepicker-rails` gem to allow my users to select a date range so they can pull reports within that given range.  I believe that I have it setup correctly, however, it doesn't look like the parameters are passing into the query.  What am I doing wrong?

These are the parameters that are being passed (could it be the date format?):

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"6ilji+8uk2/6F115tYjtwlw1JSU0KNqqUc1O26GG4Uw=", "startdate"=>"10/01/2015", "enddate"=>"10/03/2015", "commit"=>"Update"}
```

And this is the point where I noticed that no range is being passed in the logs:

```
Report Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "reports".* FROM "reports"  WHERE "reports"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "reports"."company_id" = $1 AND ("reports"."created_at" BETWEEN NULL AND NULL)  ORDER BY "reports"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0  [["company_id", 1]]
```

**reports/index.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_tag reports_index_path, method: :post, :class => "form-inline" do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_field_tag(:start_date, ((@reports.nil? || @reports.empty?) ? '' : @reports.last.created_at), class: "form-control", name: "startdate", data: {"behaviour" => "datepicker"}) %>
    <p class="text-center">to</p>
    <%= text_field_tag(:end_date, ((@reports.nil? || @reports.empty?) ? '' : @reports.first.created_at), class: "form-control", name: "enddate", data: {"behaviour" => "datepicker"}) %>
   </div>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   <%= submit_tag "Update", class: "update-button" %>
<% end %>
```

**controllers/reports_controller.rb**

```html
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @company = current_user.company

    @locations = if @company
      current_user.company_locations.order(:name)
    else
      []
    end

    unless @company.nil? || @company.reports.empty?
      if request.post?
        @reports = @company.reports.where(created_at: report_params[:start_date]..report_params[:end_date]).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      else
        @reports = @company.reports.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 30)
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def report_params
      params.permit(:start_date, :end_date)
    end

end
```

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have named your form fields `startdate` and `enddate` but your controller is looking for `start_date` and `end_date`. Please make these match and let us know if this solves the problem.
2. I think `@reports.blank?` takes care of `(@reports.nil? || @reports.empty?)` with one command.

Comment: Man, the smallest oversight... Nice catch!